# How can I use regexp (or equivalent) in MS SQL Server to solve this problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched online and in SO to try and find a solution to my problem but I can't find anyone that has solved this.

When creating a table in MS SQL Server, I have a column called `composite_name`. I want to add a constraint to this column so that it only accepts values of the form:

```
COMPOSITE1, COMPOSITE2, ..., COMPOSITE[x], ...
```

where [x] is any integer.

I have tried to do this by adding the below constraint to my table creation statement:

```
CONSTRAINT [check_composite_name] CHECK (composite_name LIKE 'COMPOSITE[0-9]+')
```

the table creates, but then when I insert data that has the form mentioned above I get an error. Clearly something is wrong with the string pattern but I'm not sure how to fix this.

I stress that I am using Microsoft SQL Server so there are no functions like `REGEXP_LIKE`. I thought I had followed the documentation correctly on this given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL Server does *not* support Regex, it only supports *basic* pattern matching. If you need Regex (which means using syntax that SQL Server's basic pattern matching doesn't support), you'll need to likely implement CLR functions.

Comment: If `'COMPOSITE'` is a constant string prefix why even store it? Just store the integer component  in an `int` column and concatenate the constant string when needed for display

Comment: @MartinSmith - this would be the ideal solution. Unfortunately the column needs to be used as a foreign key for another table that already exists and given the time constraints we can't go restructuring this data.

Comment: @Larnu - After speaking to a colleague, he agreed with you to create a function to solve this. I will post the solution we came up with shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `like` and `not like`:

```
check (composite like 'COMPOSITE[0-9]%' and
       composite not like 'COMPOSITE%[^0-9]%'
      )
```

Note:  This may also match lower case, depending on the collation of the column.